# Bootstrap Nested List Group shows both items in the Tab Content

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a page navigation feature in HTML using the Bootstrap List-group class.

How the feature should work:

When I click `Home`, show `link 1` only, and when I further click `Link 1`, show `Page 1` only.

Likewise, when I click `Profile`, show `link 2` only, and when I further click `Link 2`, show `Page 2`.

The links work fine and show the right items.

The problem is, both `Link 1` and `Link 2` show up at the same time when I click either the `Home` link or the `Profile` link.

Thanks!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="tab" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
        <a id="list-home-page" data-toggle="tab" href="#aa" role="tab" aria-controls="a">
        Link 1
        </a>
        <a id="list-profile-page" data-toggle="tab" href="#bb" role="tab" aria-controls="b">
        Link 2
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabPage">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="aa" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="aa">
    Page 1
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="bb" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bb">
    Page 2
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This seems like a confusing UX. Can you explain more about how it works in practice?

Comment: 'Link 1' should appear when 'Home' is clicked. And When 'Link 1' is clicked, 'Page 1' should appear. Likewise when 'Profile' is clicked, only 'Link 2' should appear. And when 'Link2' is clicked, 'Page 2' should appear. The problem is when I click 'home', both 'Link 1' and 'Link 2' appear.

Comment: You said all that already. I'm asking _why_ you need this arrangement.

Comment: Am new to bootstrap so please help me point out where the issue is with the arrangement.

Comment: I want 'Link 1' and 'Link 2' to behave like 'Page 1' and 'Page 2'. When one is clicked the other is absent.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it seems you've maybe conflated two concepts together in trying to create this navigation.

Usually list-group and list-group-item are used within unordered list elements like this

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">An item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
</ul>
```

While you can still used the same HTML elements (**ul and li**) if you want, you have to change the classes in bootstrap when you want to use it for navigation.

This isn't just the styling affect but also some of the JS that's used is going to be different.

Example:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I recommend checking the documentation starting in this section (link below) and refactor your code to match.

[Bootstrap 4 Tab - JavaScript Behavior](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/#javascript-behavior)

Now, tabs I would usually suggest if you want users to stay on one page but show different layers of content on that single page. If you are looking for navigation between pages like

- example.com/home
- ../about
- ../contact

Consider using the navbar instead.

[Bootstrap 4 - Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/)

One thing I would warn against is copying the code from the documentation and simply plugging in the values you want. It may work but it won't teach you anything.